# How to delete item from list and from database in android?

Tags: android, database, list

There are a lot of questions about how to delete item from list, but I couldn't find the one I am looking for.
So basically, I have a list and DB, how do I delete from both list and DB?
Because my list get populated from `ArrayList<String>` so one item is simply string. For example I have two items in my list like - 1.John,Doe 2.Jane,Doe
How do I get those items ids?
If I use this code and check id by clicking on items:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    Long.toString(parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)) , 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  }});
```

It shows 0 or 1 but not 1 or 2.(which is quite logical)
So yea, how do I get those items ids? The only option I can think now is to get my list item's first two or three chars and convert them to int and pass to my SQL statement where then I delete corresponding items from DB.
Maybe someone has any better ideas?

Edited:

```
private void getAllData()
{
    cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
            MY_TABLE, null);

    if (cursor != null)
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"));
                String persName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name"));
                String persSurname= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Surname"));
                results.add("" + id + ", " + persName + ", " + persSurname);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

And `results` is `private List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();` I hope that is what you were asking.

Comment: Can I see some code of how you're retrieving the data from the database and then how you're getting the `String` objects you want into the adapter?

Comment: @Pzanno Added code to my post.

Comment: yeah that's pretty much what I was looking for. I've posted an answer that should work for you and also suggested using the `SimpleCursorAdapter` for future lists you might create from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably extend from the [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) class instead of what you're currently doing to only pass in `String` objects. This [example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/), should get you started on putting your data into the adapter.

However, if you want to only modify what you're currently doing, I would suggest the following. In addition to your `ArrayList<String> results` I would create an additional object `ArrayList<Integer> resultsIds` that would hold the ids for each item.

```
results.add("" + id + ", " + persName + ", " + persSurname);
resultsIds.add(id);
```

Then in your click listener do the following:

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    int id = resultsIds.get(position); // this is the id for the item in the database you want to delete
    // now with your myDataBase SqliteDatabse object delete the item from the databse.
    // then remove it from the list
    ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();
    adapter.remove( results.get(position) );
    // and you'll probably now want to remove the String and id from your results
    results.remove(position);
    resultsIds.remove(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onListItemClick and the parameter id instead:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    //TODO:
}
```